How to Render Transparent Surface in Open3D with C++
I want to render several translucent surfaces. However, I've found that I can't use the RGBA format directly.
I attempted to use shaders, and consulted the official docs, only found a few classes and methods without any tutorial or examples (like open3d::visualization::rendering::Material, open3d::visualization::rendering::MaterialRecord, open3d::visualization::rendering::Renderer ...)
A protected member of open3d::visualization::Visualizer, std::unordered_set< std::shared_ptr< glsl::GeometryRenderer >> geometry_renderer_ptrs_, looks like what I want, though I can't find any methods to access it indirectly.
I also checked the github issues: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/2890, but not helpful for me.
Things in python seems much simpler,
import open3d as o3d

plane = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_box(5,0.1,2, create_uv_map=True, map_texture_to_each_face=True)
plane.compute_triangle_normals()
mat = o3d.visualization.rendering.MaterialRecord()
mat.shader = "defaultLitTransparency"
mat.albedo_img = o3d.io.read_image("../test_scripts/google_street.png")

o3d.visualization.draw({'name': 'plane', 'geometry': plane, 'material': mat})

I want to know how I can achieve the same effect as this. If possible, I would like to know how to use custom shaders with Geometries in Open3D in C++. (I really need some examples)
environment : open3d-devel-windows-amd64-0.18.0 binary library

After 2 days I found the answer.
Open3D for C++ does not provide translucent methods. I inherit the original Visualizer class and Renderer class, overwrite original shaders with my own.


Great that you found the answer to your question! Could you also provide some code to your solution for future reference to help others with the same problem?
